# how to add button that would pass and store current time in database in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

should js be used to perform the action or is there any other method to do so?
This is my attendance table.

```
create_table "attendances", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "intime"
    t.datetime "outtime"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

This is my code:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :intime %> 
    <%= f.datetime_select :intime %> 
</div> 
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :outtime %> 
    <%= f.datetime_select :outtime %> 
</div> 
<div class="actions"> 
    <%= f.submit %> 
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you show us the code you have tried so far?

Comment: <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :intime %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :intime %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :outtime %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :outtime %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

Comment: i just have created the field for intime and outime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following steps:

```
    1. Create two buttons InTime & OutTime in the form which will submit the user_id & time_type(intime or outtype) as a parameter.
    2. Create a function in the controller which will receive the above paramters & save the intime or outtime like intime = Time.now , save the record.
    3. Create the routes for the above controller.
```

Comment: regarding the function in controller. how do i create a function in the controller. can you post a sample function?

Comment: def my_fuction  attendence = Attendance.find(params[:attendance_id])  attendance.send(params[:time_type] = Time.now  attendance.save  end